# If there some way know or check some variable contains a list of dictionaries?

Tags: python, validation, types

I am writing a lambda for AWS and I want to provide detailed error messages to the caller. Among the errors I want to be able to provide is the error that inform that the format/schema of the body received has no the correct format.

The data expected should be a list of dictionaries.

When using type annotation in a regular function signature this would be something like `List[Dict]`.

But this works only for coding purposes. What would be the correct/pythonic way to check a variable contains a list of dicts?

```
def check_variable(x: List[Dict]):
    # The linters will help us to know when x is not the correct type in coding time
    # but what I want is to know if x is actually a List[Dict] in the 
    # following line.
    check_x(x)
```

What's the best way to implement `check_x` not involving any loop like solution?

Of course I open to the possibility this is not possible without a loop like solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could write it as:

`return all(isinstance(d, dict) for d in x)`

Comment: While code-only answers might answer the question, you could significantly improve the quality of your answer by providing context for your code, 
a reason for why this code works, and some references to documentation for further reading.
From [answer]: _"Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better."_

Answer (score 0):

```
lst = [{"name" : ["Joe", "Anna", "John"]}, ["anderson", "larson", "johnson"]]

for i in lst:
    if isinstance(i, dict):
        print(i)
```

this will give you the dict:

output:

**{'name': ['Joe', 'Anna', 'John']}**